# How do I view the content of a very large file at position in Linux?

Tags: linux, vim, less

I've got a file containing JSON data that is about 90MB of size and has one line. I need to go to position 99376229. Unfortunately vim and less both crash when I try moving to that column.

How can I look at the content at this position or rather the data around it? I am looking for a syntax error in the data that leads to my JSON parser breaking.

I'll go for any kind of solution, also programmatical ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python:

```
$ python
>>> f = open("file.json", "r")
>>> f.seek(99376229)
>>> f.read(1024)
```

Shell:

```
$ tail -c +99376229 file.json | head -c 1K
```

Also, try piping the file through `jshon`, `json_pp`, or `json_reformat`; they'll probably give better error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the cut command from GNU coreutils. It can deal with character positions as well as fields too... See
 `$ man 1 cut` 
for more details.